# pytest hook to access durations

Tags: pytest, python-3.7

When I run my tests with xdist and durations `pytest -n 3 --durations=10`, pytest gives me a console output like so:

```
=========================== slowest 10 test durations ===========================
409.46s setup    test/cases/test_one.py::TestOne::test_one
189.82s call     test/cases/test_two.py::TestTwo::test_two   
...
...
```

**Background**: I would like to have programmatic access to these results so that we can keep a granular track record of slow tests, especially to identify slow tests & fixtures.

**Question**: Is there a way to access this information via pytest hook?

Answer (score 3):

The time is stored in the [`duration`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html#pytest.reports.TestReport.duration) field of the `TestReport` object, so it's accessible in all reporting hooks. Examples:

```
def pytest_report_teststatus(report, config):
    if report.when == "call":
        print("duration reported immediately after test execution:", report.duration)

def pytest_terminal_summary(terminalreporter, exitstatus, config):
    for reps in terminalreporter.stats.values():
        for rep in reps:
            if rep.when == "call":
                print("duration reported after all tests passed:", rep.nodeid, rep.duration)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you @hoefling!

Comment: Glad I could help!